# Parse error: syntax error in PHP

Tags: php

I try to store a string to a PHP variable.  But it shows an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='"
Here is the code

```
$page-title = "Home Page";
```

Comment: PHP variables can't contain a minus sign. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php (What PHP does here is: `variable - constant = "string";` and the equal sign is unexpected here)

Comment: $pagetitle = "Home Page"; like this no dash

Comment: its showing Dash Error which you using in your Variable Try : 
$page_title = "Home Page";

Comment: Thank you very much.  Avoid Dash.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
$page_title = "Home Page";
```

Comment: *Why* should OP do it like this?

Comment: @Rizier123: What will be your answer?

Comment: If you just give OP some code he will never know what he did wrong, so an explanation why OP has to do it like this will improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$page-title = "Home Page";`

with: `$page_title = "Home Page";`

The variable you used is wrong. PHP variables cant contain `-` signs.

Comment: *Why* should OP do it like this?

Comment: You right, i should be more clear

Answer (score 0):

**Your variable name is incorrect.**

A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ ).

Comment: You should be write as comment, not by an answer.

Comment: PHP variables can contain a bit more than alpha-numeric characters, see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php . But it is correct, that the OP's variable name is invalid due to the minus sign in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it either `$pageTitle` or `$page_title` as your variable name 
fore more detail refer php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php)

Answer (score 0):

you have use - subtraction sign in declaring variable that's why it cause an error  you can check here how to declare php variables[how to declare php variables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp)

try this

```html
$page_title = "Home Page";
```

Comment: *Why* should OP "try this"?

Comment: @Rizier123 coz   - is used as arithmetic operator so it cause an error    ................  Take a look here  ,.....http://trainingphp.blogspot.com/2011/03/naming-rules-for-variables-variable.html  .............................

Comment: @Rizier123             take a look here how to declare PHP variable http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp

Comment: Put that information inside your answer.

Comment: @Rizier123 okay now so vote up me